# call java swing JFrame from javaFx window

Tags: swing, javafx

I have a javaFx button, I need to call a JFrame (swing) on click, I tried this code but the methode doesn't appear on javaFx scene builder

```
@FXML
private Button button;

public void afficheGraph(String sys) throws Exception{

    graph frm = new graph(id);//the swing JFrame
    frm.setVisible(true);
}
```

I had this error

> Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#afficheGraph', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.

Comment: I don't see any sizing. Are you just not seeing the window appear?

Comment: I've edited the post with the error

Comment: Can you add the fxml code ? Have you added a controller to your file.fxml ?

Comment: Refer to the "Controller Event Handlers" section of the [Introduction to FXML reference guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controller_method_event_handlers) for an example of adding a button handler method.   The type parameter of the button handler method (if it is present) needs to be ActionEvent, not String (as pointed out in Bo's answer).

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken the error comes from the method itself and its parameter, I think that you need to add an annotation `@FXML` so that the method is taken in count, and I do not see the reason to add the `String sys` parameter Nor the throwable. Here is a substitution :

```
@FXML
public void afficheGraph(ActionEvent ae){ //ActionEvent instead of String
graph frm = new graph(id);//the swing JFrame
frm.setVisible(true);
}
```

I can be wrong on the throwbale but I do not see the interest, good luck !

Comment: You don't need the `@FXML` annotation on `public` methods (though imho it is far, far better to make the method non-public and annotate it). You do however need a compatible list of parameters: it must either has no parameters, or a single parameter that can be assigned the appropriate type of event (`ActionEvent` in this case, so the parameter must be `ActionEvent` or a superclass).